# tomcat not sending the requested http-header

Tags: java, tomcat, http-headers

I have got a `servlet` deployed under `tomcat/webapps` directory and I try to send a `curl` request to it:

```
 $~ curl -v http://localhost:8080/

* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x33e0ee0
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x33e0ee0) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=<ID>; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Location: http://localhost:8080/
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=EUC-KR
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Mon, 02 Sep 2013 14:24:53 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

This is the web.xml file:

```
     ...
     <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>vController</display-name>
        <servlet-name>vController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vc.cac.controller.vlController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>vController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/vController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
       <listener>
    <listener-class>com.vc.cac.controller.vlController</listener-class>
    </listener>
    ...
```

in the servlet I tried to print the `Host` element from header:

```
String host = request.getHeader("Host");
System.out.println("Host: "+host);
```

but I get `null`, so If I try to print any header element I get `null` as a result. any help?

Comment: Does `curl` send the `Host` header?

Comment: Which servlet is trying to get the header? Are you responding with 302 or the container?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: its the `my-app` servlet placed as `tomcat` root, I just execute the curl but I get nothing in the header..

Comment: Please post the minimized servlet code, the `web.xml` and the context path of your application. We must be missing something.

Comment: Your servlet is mapped to `/vController`. You should be curling on `http://localhost:8080/yourapp/vController`. Where `yourapp` is your application context path.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I do this in the index page via forward: `<jsp:forward page="/vController" />`s in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Tomcat 7.0.22, the following servlet

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/vController")
public class vlController extends HttpServlet {    
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String host = request.getHeader("Host");
        System.out.println("Host: "+host);
        resp.getWriter().write("host printed");
    }
}
```

with an `index.jsp`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:forward page="/vController" />
    Heello wRoldasdas
</body>
</html>
```

The `cURL` command prints

```
$ clear; curl -v http://localhost:8080/
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* 0x60002d0f0 is at send pipe head!
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x60006cac0; line 1032 (connection #0)
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => DO handle 0x60006cac0; line 1151 (connection #0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
>
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x60006cac0; line 1236 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x60006cac0; line 1352 (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x60006cac0; line 1363 (connection #0)
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=7694BACEC0C311357E72DCEA7574540A; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=7694BACEC0C311357E72DCEA7574540A; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Content-Length: 12
Content-Length: 12
< Date: Mon, 02 Sep 2013 16:40:11 GMT
Date: Mon, 02 Sep 2013 16:40:11 GMT

<
* STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x60006cac0; line 1533 (connection #0)
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
host printed
```

And the server clearly prints

```
Host: localhost:8080
```

In your case, the server responds with 302, so your servlet is never hit. I don't know where your `null` header is coming from.

Instead of with `cURL`, try with a Java HTTP client, ex. Apache's `HttpClient`.

Comment: It hits the servlet because I can get all the debugging messages inside the `doGet` method.. `302` is because of the url redirection in `vController`

Comment: @stsd What was the problem?